# Manage webpage with HttpWebRequest

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to manage a webpage (aspx, html, php etc), in terms of injecting or deleting code inside the page using HttpWebRequest and Jquery?

What i want to do is :

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.xxxxxxxxx.gr/newsletter.html")
Dim hresponse As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim dataStream As Stream = hresponse.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
responseStr = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

and then inject or delete code from inside the page and then save it.

Comment: Where do you want to save the page, locally or replacing the page you fetched?

Comment: I want to modify the page by injecting or deleting code inside it, and then reupload it to the server...

Comment: Much like what Filezilla does...online edit and then re-save on the server...but with asp.net and jquery if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use HttpWebRequest in the backend of your ASP application. But you can not (or at least should not) inject or modify code in an existing aspx/html page. Even if it would work, it will only lead to confusion, bugs and is bad style.

What you can do is to insert the data you got via HttpWebRequest dynamically into your current response. If you don't want to send the http request every time you need the data, you can cache it. I can not give more details, since you have not given details about what you want to achieve. This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [WebDAV protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), which is an established standard for performing remote editing of web server resources, that is supported by most web server types. [Here is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2010/02/09/sending-webdav-requests-in-net.aspx) a simple example of performing WebDAV commands using C#.

Comment: Note that you need to enable WebDAV on the web server in question.